# Google overasking permissions?

Tags: android, permissions

I am updating an app that I uploaded like 6 months ago and now is asking for 7 new permissions! The app is entirely offline, no ads. The only think that would need internet is a button that leads the user to the rating site in Google Play but that button was there before. The whole list is:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE maxSdkVersion=18
android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Is this normal? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If that's what Google is suggesting, then just add those permissions in.  It's there to let users know what your app is intending.  This includes things that you have in your code that do other things.  This is why, if you run AdMob (or something), new permissions are required even though the entire rest of your app doesn't use them.

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid permission: `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE maxSdkVersion=18`

Comment: See also this blog post on the subject: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html